# Accidentally used plumbing flux on a PCB; How do I remove it to reuse the board?

Tags: pcb-assembly, flux, reuse

Two weeks ago, I picked the wrong tub of flux from my toolbox and used it for making a 9VAC -> 5VDC adapter. I fluxed all the components and soldered it down before realising I was using **PLUMBING** flux!

The solder pads are all still intact and I've tested the conductivity of the leads of all my parts; they are all intact.

So to summarize,

How should I remove the flux after desoldering in such a way that I can reuse the PCB?

and

I may have used small amounts on other repairs in the past (all of them my own personal projects, none for others). Will I have to worry too much about these?

The flux is labeled as  "alpha metals" brand "soldering paste flux".

Comment: Plumbing flux does essentially the same thing as soldering flux.  I don't see why this is an issue unless the flux itself is conductive.  It should not harm any of the metals and since its plumbing flux I doubt its meant to be cleaned up.

Comment: Plumbing flux will corrode the PCB over time. it's acidic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clean my boards from flux with isopropyl alcohol and a paintbrush , I'm not sure what is different about plumbing flux that could prevent it from getting cleaned the same way.

If the flux is not mented all the way maybe a hot air gun will help get rid the majority of it (melted it can be wiped easily or drip away) and then just wipe the excess.
Another idea is to try with water first in case the flux is water water-soluble and then use the isopropyl alcohol

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am not sure if this will work, but am assuming it to since I've seen this about rosin core flux anyway. Since I haven't tried yet, just upvoting for now. I will mark an answer after I have tested it.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 , I've made a couple of additions to the reply, maybe they help, in any case it would be beneficial to post your results when you try.

Comment: Adding info about the type of flux in question to my question. Also posting here. It is "alpha metals" brand "soldering paste flux".

Comment: @Wyatt8740 any specific code number?

Comment: Yeah, it says 'cat no. 51012' at the bottom. It says on the box card that is ISO 9002 and the part number on the card says 51011. The image of the tin and box is here. http://i.walmartimages.com/i/mp/00/03/14/27/51/0003142751011_P255045_500X500.jpg also i picked up some rosin flux from radio shack since I can't wait for delivery and Fort Wayne doesn't have a better electronics store anymore (used to be a place called pembleton's electronics).

Comment: alpha metals has nothing about 51012 product code so no help from there

Comment: If only I didn't have to pay money for ISO standards. It would make finding out what ISO 9002 is much easier.

Comment: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9002 it'about quality so i would not worry about in this context.

Comment: for some reason the 'mark as answer' icon is not appearing. when it finally does I can mark this as the answer. thank you!

Comment: @Wyatt8740 I'm glad you solved the problem. I have no idea about the `mark as solved` symbol and why it can be missing.

Comment: @alexan_e it's back now :D Thanks for your help ^_^